# gsheet importjson query for parsing JSONSchema

Tags: json, google-apps-script

Using ImportJSON to parse JSONSchema documents and load into GSheet.

I have JSON documents with paths as in the snip below.

I want to output the names of properties in one column and the type in another.

Wanted to see if someone has done this already before i start hacking about with parseJSON or the defaultTransform functions of ImportJSON.

Added example GSheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r1W3-2NPd3D7zZ3IZ73pJDU2V0_xIwm2W8iXHGVCi5I/edit#gid=1847025375)

Shows source, currently parsed output and what i need in terms of required output

```
/data/schema/properties/plan_id/type
/data/schema/properties/plan_id/maxLength
/data/schema/properties/plan_name/type
/data/schema/properties/plan_name/maxLength
/data/schema/properties/type/type
/data/schema/properties/type/maxLength
/data/schema/properties/quantity_ranges/type
/data/schema/properties/quantity_ranges/maximum
/data/schema/properties/quantity_ranges/minimum
/data/schema/properties/pricing_option/type
/data/schema/properties/pricing_option/maxLength
/data/schema/properties/currency/type
/data/schema/properties/currency/enum
/data/schema/properties/value/type
/data/schema/properties/value/maximum
/data/schema/properties/value/minimum
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `ImportJSON` is a Google Apps Script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script and the values in your question? And also, can you provide the output you expect? Because I cannot understand about `the names of properties in one column and the type`. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. When I saw your DesiredOutput, unfortunately, I thought that it cannot be achieve by only ImportJSONFromSheet. So I think that it is required to prepare a script for retrieving your DesiredOutput. How about this? By the way, in your DesiredOutput, the values of "maxLength" and "maximum" are put to the same column. This is the result you want?

Comment: I have concluded the same thing. Sometimes you just have to build it yourself!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation.

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

When you use this sample script, please put `=parseObject("SourceJSON!A1")` to a cell in your shared Spreadsheet.

```
function parseObject(range) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range);
  var value = range.getValue();
  var object = JSON.parse(value);
  var res = [];
  var headers = ["type", ["maxLength", "maximum"], "minimum", "enum"];
//  var headers = ["type", "maxLength", "maximum", "minimum", "enum"];
  for (var i in object.data.schema.properties) {
    var obj = object.data.schema.properties[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      var temp = [object.data.id, object.data.version];
      if (Array.isArray(headers[j])) {
        for (var k = 0; k < headers[j].length; k++) {
          if (obj[headers[j][k]]) res.push(temp.concat([i, "",obj[headers[j][k]],"",""]));
        }
      } else {
      if (obj[headers[j]]) {
          var ar = [i, "","","",""];
          ar.splice(j + 1, 1, Array.isArray(obj[headers[j]]) ? obj[headers[j]].join(",") : obj[headers[j]]);
          res.push(temp.concat(ar));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script retrieves the data from the Spreadsheet.
- In your DesiredOutput, the values of "maxLength" and "maximum" in the data are put to the same column. At above sample script, the result is the same with it. If you want to separate the values of "maxLength" and "maximum", please modify `var headers = ["type", ["maxLength", "maximum"], "minimum", "enum"];` to `var headers = ["type", "maxLength", "maximum", "minimum", "enum"];`.
- This sample script is for the value in your shared Spreadsheet. So when you use this for the data with other structure, an error might occur and/or the result you don't want might be returned. Please be careful this.

Comment: Certainly works.
Trying to pick it apart so i can see where to modify it to make it more extensible. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Simon Taylor Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you , too.